# How to make a liquid metal effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I was wondering if anyone could help me. So I've been trying to make a liquid metal effect in photoshop and I'm having some trouble. I wanted to know if anyone had any idea on how to achieve this effect similar to the image I added. I've searched the internet on tutorials on how to get it done, but nothing comes close. I understand how to make the ripple effect as well as adding the chrome-like effect, but can't get it to be multiple colors like the image added. if anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be amazing! Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1):

looks to me like an image of neon lighting which has been liquified.... using the liquify tools.

Comment: It isn't. There's repeating parts. Nobody can brush that precisely.

Comment: @user287001 The repeating parts could have been added later, by copy pasting. I think liquifying is still a possible solution.

Comment: Seems to be true, now I can see a faded seam. Thanks for the rectification.

Answer (score 0):

A really quick test:

1. Some random strokes with a blurred brush

[image]

2. Then apply some liquify filter pulling down.

[image]

Then add a gradient fill layer on top and play with the colors.

[image]

Duplicated layer, moved a bit with a different blending mode.

[image]

This is a really quick test. The truth is that it will be a bit difficult to make predictable results, but who knows.

Probably you need to work with different layers, making some shapes here and some shapes there. Adding some different blending modes perhaps.

---

I would explore a real 3D object.

Using Blender

1. Making a fluid simulation, taking one frame of an organic shape.
2. Making a chromed material.
3. A light source with patterns on it.